# How to change AWS environment variables with ShellCommandActivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to dynamically increment my environment variables (dates) for my AWS datapipeline and was wondering if someone has achieved this through ShellCommandActivity by changing the config.json file?

```
{
    "values": ..{}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. You can use nested expressions in your pipeline definition anywhere;

```
#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd')}
```

E.g. as parameters you can use in your "command":

```
 "parameters": [
    {
      "id": "myDate",
      "type" : "DateTime"
    }
  ],
  "values": {
    "myDate": "#{minusDays(myDateTime,1)}"
  }
```

Or get a date as part of the shell command that is being executed:

`date -v -1d`

More info:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-expressions.html